# Fundamental Thm of calculus(version 2)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let the $f(x,y)\in C^{2}(R^2)$(continuous and differentiable)

By F.T.C, I've just known the fact that

$\int_a^{b}f_x(t,y)dt$ = $f(b,y)-f(a,y)$

$\int_a^{b}f_y(x,t)dt$ = $f(x,b)-f(x,a)$

But what about the case, $\int_a^{b}f_x(x,t)dt$ ?

Actually I guess the answer was $f_x(x,b)-f_x(x,a)$, But when it comes to this cases, the F.T.C. can't be utilized.

Comment: $\int_a^bf_y(x,t)dt$ should be $f(x,b)-f(x,a)$ instead.

Comment: Thanks for point out. I just edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to say anything in general. You are differentiating w.r.t one variable and integrating w.r.t. another variable, so you don't have any formula for this integral.

Answer (score 0):

You can use chain rule. $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} dt = \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} \frac{\partial t}{\partial x} dt$. If you know $\frac{\partial t}{\partial x}$, you can use ftoc or integration by parts depending the result.